# How to remove index.php in url while working on Codeigniter-WAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have seen many questions about my problem there are number of solutions i tried them all!i'm facing this problem from from 24 hours and not able to move forward.

these steps i have taken simply.

1)install codeigniter.
2)enable rewrite_mod by removing # sign.in appache httpd.conf file
3)these changings in confing.php file

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ciblog';
$config['index_page'] = '';

4)new .htaccess file in www/ciblog folder which have these lines

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|
uploads|favicon.png)

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

and it troughs an error that
 "The requested URL /ciblog/welcome was not found on this server."

Please help me specifically i'm using WAMP server.

thnks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart apache after editing the config?

Comment: Did you enable apache mod_rewrite wamp

Comment: yes i have restrated apache and i have enabled mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `VHOST`.

in `/etc/hosts` (or c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) add:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.whatever.com
```

Then, in Apache's `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, set up your `VirtualHost`, here's an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/bonemvc/public"
    ServerName dev.whatever.com
    FallbackResource index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/bonemvc">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, open Apache's `httpd.conf` and look for vhost, uncomment the line so the other conf file will load.

Close your browsers, restart apache, reopen your browser, and head to `http://dev.whatever.com`. You should get your home page without the index.php showing!

Comment: not working i added this code in http-vhosts.conf file 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\ciblog\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <directory "c:\wamp\www\ciblog\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: and uncoment this line in httpd.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

and i have checked 127.0.0.1  localhost line is there in  (c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts)

Comment: you have DocumentRoot and Directory wrong. Look closely at mine!

Comment: hey! now i'm accessing this address::(localhost/ciblog/index.php/welcome)
by simply (localhost) please guide me wheres the problem.

now i'm not able to access localhost homepage.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ciblog/"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/ciblog/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: docroot should be in the `public` folder. Again, check the differences in my `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`!

Comment: and add a fake domain name into your hosts and vhost config, don't use localhost!

Comment: i want to access my index.php page with this link(localhost/ciblog/welcome).now i'm able to access with (localhost/welcome) and also now i'm able to access with(myweb/)which is fake domain

Comment: Again, don't use localhost! Add `127.0.0.1 ciblog` to your hosts file, change the vhost domain to `ciblog`, and then you can call `http://ciblog`. Other sites? Add another vhost and hosts file entry! It will act like an actual online domain rather than a subfolder of localhost, which is a problem my Codeigniter pal Dave was constantly getting until I sorted him out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And Also you need to search and replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

in config.php

Comment: no difference with this .htaccess

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI" this line was already with this value.

Comment: @Moneeb Add a "/" like this  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ciblog/'; . and try after restarting your wamp.as you had changed the apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in **.htaccess** file:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

I Hope this working fine for xampp and wamp server
if you still have issue so please share details with me.